# Laravel post error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting the following error message when trying to update user data:

```
 protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
    {
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
    }
```

I'm logging the user in, then want to give them the option to change their preferences. The form displays fine in the view but won't post.

**Here are my routes:**

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
Route::get('/', 'AdminsController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
Route::post('/', 'AdminsController@update')->name('admin.dashboard.update');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
```

**Here's the Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Admin;
use Auth;

class AdminsController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $admin = Admin::find($id);
    return view('admin')->with('admin',$admin);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $this-> validate($request, [
      'target_sector' => 'required|max:255',
      'target_skillsets' => 'required|max:255',
      'target_companies'=> 'required|max:255',
      'target_locations'=> 'required|max:255',

  ]);
  //Create Post
  $id = Auth::user()->id;
  $admin = Admin::find($id);
  $admin->target_sector = $request->input('target_sector');
  $admin->target_skillsets = $request->input('target_skillsets');
  $admin->target_companies = $request->input('target_companies');
  $admin->target_locations = $request->input('target_locations');

  $admin->save();

  return redirect('/admin')->with('success', 'Preferences Updated', 'admin',$admin);
}

}
```

**And here is the view:**

```
@include('includes.nav_login')
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Admin Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    You are logged in as ADMIN!
                </div>
                <div class="card-header">Update Vacancy Preferences</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                   {!! Form::open(['action' => ['AdminsController@update', $admin], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

                    <div class="form-group">
                      {{Form::label('companies', 'Companies')}}
                      {{Form::text('companies', $admin->target_companies,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Target Companies'])}}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      {{Form::label('skillsets', 'Skillsets')}}
                      {{Form::text('skillsets', $admin->target_skillsets,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Skillsets'])}}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      {{Form::label('sector', 'Sector')}}
                      {{Form::text('sector', $admin->target_sector,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Sector'])}}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      {{Form::label('locations', 'Locations')}}
                      {{Form::text('locations', $admin->target_locations,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Locations'])}}
                    </div>

                      {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
                      {{Form::submit('Update',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix you route, because you are using `put` method for update, but on routes, you defined as post

```
Route::post('/', 'AdminsController@update')->name('admin.dashboard.update');
```

Therefore error occurs.

You should fix your route like this,

```
Route::put('/{id}', 'AdminsController@update')->name('admin.dashboard.update');
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks webdevtr - this was it! There were a few more errors I had to sort out by following the subsequent issues but this was closest.

Answer (score 0):

The error says MethodNotAllowed which means you are hitting a route with a different request method than it accepts

you open the form like this

```
 {!! Form::open(['action' => ['AdminsController@update', $admin], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

so till now the form method is POST

but then you spoof the method to be of type put

```
{{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
```

so now the method becomes of type put not post

however your route expects the method to be post

```
Route::post('/', 'AdminsController@update')->name('admin.dashboard.update');
```

This is why you get method not allowed exception

you either change the method on your controller to be put instead of post or remove the method spoofing thing from inside your form

I mean this line

```
//remove this
{{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
```

once you fix it you will have another error because you don't have csrf field in your form so just add this inside of your form

```
@csrf
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed overview! Whilst this didn't fix things for me, it definitely gave me a better understanding of how this works. The answer from @webdevtr got it working but I really appreciate your thorough response.

Answer (score 0):

Really appreciate both answers on here - thanks @Mohammad Instanboli and @webdevtr.

Webdevtr was right to advise this:

```
Route::put('/{id}', 'AdminsController@update')->name('admin.dashboard.update');
```

I also had to go back and fix the following which I thought would be useful to note if anyone else views this with a similar issue:

Firstly my AdminsController@update method needed the following changes:

I changed the public function update to take one less variable - ($id)

```
    public function update(Request $request)
{
  $this-> validate($request, [
      'target_sector' => 'required|max:255',
      'target_skillsets' => 'required|max:255',
      'target_companies'=> 'required|max:255',
      'target_locations'=> 'required|max:255',

  ]);
  //Create Post
  $id = Auth::user()->id;
  $admin = Admin::find($id);
  $admin->target_sector = $request->input('target_sector');
  $admin->target_skillsets = $request->input('target_skillsets');
  $admin->target_companies = $request->input('target_companies');
  $admin->target_locations = $request->input('target_locations');

  $admin->save();

  return redirect('/admin')->with('success', 'Preferences Updated', 'admin',$admin);
}
```

Then I needed to make sure the $request->input('x') matched the input names in the form in my view - i.e:

```
<div class="form-group">
                  {{Form::label('target_sector', 'target_sector')}}
                  {{Form::text('target_sector', $admin->target_sector,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Sector'])}}
                </div>
```